# How can I improve a remote desktop connection across long distance?

Tags: remote-access

I require connecting to someones PC to complete a video game level (small windowed client) and usually when I connect using Teamviewer/Splashtop to someone who lives within europe i get a good low latency connection, almost as if it is their own pc.

However connecting to people in USA/Asia, I get really bad/pingy connections. I normally use a 50mb fibre connection and the other party has 100mb+ usually but we still get a slow/less responsive connection.

It may seem obvious but is this simply down to distance between the two points? (europe to usa). Is there a particular way for me to connection to another PC with almost 0 delay like I get when remote connecting to someone in my country? I have used Splashtop so far since I find it to be the best responsive program,

Comment: @dsstorefile1 What does this mean sorry?

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is quite tardy, but I recommend that you utilize the program "LogMeIn Hamachi". It sanctions you to join or engender a local network point, so that when any device connects to it, no matter how far away it is, it will be registered as local, consequently incrementing your connectivity speed. (At least, this is as far as i'm concerned.)

I cerebrate VPN's work additionally.

You can withal use "uVNC" (Windows only). Albeit uVNC is a lot more tedious and advanced to use.

If none of these work, feel in liberty to ask me to probe for more methods, i'm up for the task.